# jquery show or hide checkbox based on action

Tags: jquery, checkbox, show

I'm looking to show or hide a series of checkboxes based on a click of a link. I'm pretty sure this is achievable using jQuery but haven't found a good reference on stackoverflow (yet).

```
<input type="checkbox" value=someval>
```

I'm guessing I need to add a class to the input box, then have jquery toggle the show/hide attribute?

Comment: yes.... where is the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the chckbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="myitems" value=someval>
```

then

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('mylink').click(function(){
        $('.myitems').toggle();
    })
})
```